# Displaying many to many data in SQL Server in visual studio using c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I know this is possible but I can't think of a way to display this.

Assume that a doctor can have many specialization.

DOCTOR :- `DOC_ID, DOC_NAME, SPEC_ID`

then a table that is a foreign key to the former, namely

SPECIALIZATION :- `SPEC_ID, SPEC_NAME`

Then the linking table "I forgot what is the technical term for this" that is a foreign key respectively, namely

DOCTORSPECIALIZATION :- `DOC_ID, SPEC_ID`

How to display this in visual studio?

Comment: How do you plan to access the data in the database?

Comment: Are you asking how you'd build an object representing this relationship or how you'd access the data?

Comment: Are you sure this is one-to-many relationship? It sounds more like a many-to-many to me (one doctor can have multiple specializations, and each specialization can be "owned" by many doctors)

Comment: yeah sorry i got carried away while typing the title. Yep it is many to many

Comment: @scott, i want to insert then query it.

Comment: @DanS, im sorry mister but i don't understand can you please translate it in more laymans term? :)

Comment: I was asking if you were trying to figure out how you'd construct a c# class representing a doctor with many specialties, i.e. `public class Doctor { public List<string> Specialties { get; set; } }`, or if you were asking how you'd use c# to interact with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to do this, first In SQL and second is C# code.

```
In SQL:- 

DECLARE @DOC_ID = 1234
1. Fetch Doctor SPEC Name and Take into Temp table
   CREATE TABLE #tempDOC_SPEC             
    (             
      SPEC_ID int,             
      SPEC_NAME varchar(100)        
    )        

   INSERT INTO #tempDOC_SPEC
   SELECT SPECIALIZATION.SPEC_ID, SPECIALIZATION.SPEC_NAME
   FROM DOCTORSPECIALIZATION a INNER JOIN SPECIALIZATION b ON a.SPEC_ID = b.SPEC_ID
   WHERE DOC_ID = @DOC_ID

2. Stuff data from this temp table to get desired results    

 SELECT DOC_ID, DOC_NAME, 
 STUFF((Select ', '+ #tempDOC_SPEC.SPEC_NAME FROM tempDOC_SPEC FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
 AS SPEC_Name
 FROM DOCTOR
 WHERE DOC_ID = @DOC_ID
```

This SQL query give the Doc name, Spec_Name as comma separated value in single column.

```
In C#:- 
we have to loop through for each Doctor name and display the Spec_Name.
```